# New button on pages library takes me to Upload document page

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

It's weird but it's true. If I click the new button on a document library it takes me to the 'Upload Document' page and not the 'Create Page' page, which is strange as it used to work correctly.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, check the template url for the default content type on your pages library. It should say /_layouts/CreatePage.aspx. To do this:-

1. Go to Pages library settings
2. Click the content type that has the default indicator
3. Advanced settings